# Unable to install 'cordova-plugin-ms-adal' on ionic -4 (ios)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, platform

Issue -
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-ms-adal': CordovaError: Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "fs" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.

Configuration -
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
@angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : none
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 27 other plugins)

System:

ios-deploy : 1.10.0
NodeJS     : v12.13.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm        : 6.12.1
OS         : macOS Catalina
Xcode      : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504

Comment: I am also facing the same problem! Do you have a solution?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed this issue using "cordova-plugin-ms-adal-is-back" plugin.